# Plis I wish indications a site to train automated software testing

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rspec-rails

describe 'Visit script' do

it 'visitar a pagina' do

```
puts "visitando a pagina"

visit "https://www.google.com/"

expect(page.title).to eql "Google"
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the standard RSpec matchers with Capybara objects - the standard matchers don't have waiting/retrying behavior.  Instead use the Capybara provided matchers

```
it 'visitar a pagina' do
  puts "visitando a pagina"
  visit "https://www.google.com/"
  expect(page).to have_title("Google")
end
```